# How to append a value dynamically every time in a file for a existing variable in unix?

Tags: sql, shell, unix

I have a requirement where i have to append a value the 1st time and overwrite it the next(subsequent) times. say, i append a variable `key_id=1000` to an already existing file.

Next time on executing script i should overwrite 1000 by another value say 1245.

this changes each time the script is run. ( The input is fetched from a separate file ),

Can anyone help me out with this. Right im getting the value appended. i'e i have two instance of key_id on 2nd run **(as `Key_id=1000 key_id=1245`)**  and 3 on 3rd run.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your file name is `/var/keyVal.out` 
and it contains:

```
key_id=1000
```

so to replace its content with new value you can use following code:

```
sed -i "s/key_id=.*/key_id=NEW_VALUE/g" /var/keyVal.out
```

at place of NEW_VALUE you can pass your new value for `key_id`.

Comment: This is perhaps the __most__ [useless use of cat](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html) I've come across in a long while!

Comment: sed **-i** "s/key_id=.*/key_id=NEW_VALUE/g" /var/keyVal.out